# Is Batman in "The Dark Knight Returns" acting out of character compared to the "canon Batman"?

Tags: dc, batman, dark-knight-returns

Me and my friend recently had an argument regarding Miller's *The Dark Knight Returns* story. Namely, my friend (who is far more familiar with Batman comics and DC comics in general) claims that its portrayal of Batman is so vastly different from "canon Batman" in order to make the story, work which makes the whole DKR look silly and unrealistic.

Namely, he is referring to the fact Batman retired 10 years prior to the comic's beginning (and not to Batman's actions in the comics itself) and these are the things he names that make no sense for "canon Batman" to do:

- Generally, Batman would never give up on being a vigilante, as long as there's still crime to fight (which, as it seems, DKR universe is full of).
- Robin's death would not cause Batman to simply give up (as seen in "*A Death in the Family*").
- Batman would not allow pressure from the government to affect him, even with Superman being part of it.

Is there any indication in "canon" comics that, given the circumstances presented in DKR, Batman would act the way he did (completely retiring and giving up the life of a vigilante) or was this noticeably out-of-character for Batman to do?

Comment: Some people get more cynical with age.

Comment: One might argue that, at the point when DKR was printed, "cannon" Batman's character was not that well developed. DKR influenced Post-Crisis cannon Batman a lot, transferring attributes of the elderly Batman to his newly rebooted, younger, self. I will admit to being hazy on the finer points of the pre-Crisis Batman's character, but it is safe to say that he was less single-minded then his successors.

Comment: That sounds reasonable and, considering there weren't any other answers offered, could you rewrite it as an answer so that I can choose it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think part of Batman's retirement in DKR is a massive reduction in crime. All of Batman's villains are out of action at the beginning of DKR. He likely went along with the government because it was better for Gotham if he did. He wasn't necessary any more.

Comment: I was fully expecting one of the bullet points to be about DKR Batman using a gun.

Comment: “makes the whole DKR look silly and unrealistic” — as opposed to the [sensible](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Bat-Mite) and [realistic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150145/in-what-issue-did-batman-survive-the-vacuum-of-space) regular Batman comics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frank Miller is a prolific writer and **avid** Batman fan, but his stance of how this Bruce would be at that age is *not* in line with "Canon" Batman. By that, he does have the intense, solitary nature, disdain for crime and sparkling anti-social personality... but they are **turned up to *11,*** added with some old-man bitterness/disillusionment, and grounded in the grim/dark "gritty" so-called "Realism" that the mid-to-late 80s, Post-Rambo world had come to expect from its "heroes". This, essentially, was a bit of a counter to the 1960s "campy" Adam West Batman, and the early 80s "white bread" cartoon version of super heroes [including the "Super Friends" Batman].

Now, originally [as in his 1939 debut] Batman *was* darker in tone and a bit more liberal with killing, but that was due to his connection to the pulp-heroes at the time. This didn't even last 3 years; the no-killing was instituted fairly early on, most firearms were removed, and by the 40s, while a vigilante, his reasoning was for the *protection* of human life. These elements became fixtures [especially post the game changing *Seduction of the Innocent* ] as the funny-book 40s, the Norman Rockwell-eque 50s, and the campy 60s went on. Batman's tone got *slightly* darker in the anti-establishment 70s, but by the optimistic 80s, he was still a firmly "Good guy" hero. Due to the impact of various social conditions in America, the whole "grim dark" aesthetic and muscular, attitude carrying, brutal heroes became the norm.... and Batman (with his already darker origins) was a natural fit for these changes. This is one reason why Miller's **TDKR** resonated as it did, especially as mainstream comics were becoming more mature in their stories at that time.

Due to the impact of Miller's work and the aforementioned social changes, *his* version of Batman--- a brooding, sullen, something of an anti-hero, grim Dark Knight--- became somewhat of a "Default," and began influencing almost *every version* of the character that came **after** it. Even the 1989 Tim Burton version of the hero, which was arguably more balanced portrayal in some ways, took *some* inspiration from Miller's dark tone and grittiness; note the guns in the Batmobile, and Bruce's tendency to silent violence in the first film. To mention nothing of the number of people the Joker killed in that movie...and this was [mostly] a kid's film in the *80s!*

So while not "canon" in itself, Miller's version has, to a degree, help *shape* the future canon of Batman. **Most** versions of Bruce still hold darkness and intensity, but *not* to the grim-dark, anti-humanity level that Miller's pessimistic, nearly hopeless and pitiless Batman takes it. The DCAU version *probably* struck the best overall balance in this regard:

*That* Batman---voiced for 20+ years by Kevin Conroy, and which many look to as the definitive version--- is intense, controlling, has issues and *can* be brutal... but he is **no killer,** has *obvious* compassion, **despises** guns [even with rubber bullets], and does what he does *not* to punish criminals alone, but to prevent the tragedy that happened to him from happening to anyone else, where he is able to. Oddly enough, Amanda Waller, a hard-nosed often antagonist and well-intentioned extremist in the DCAU probably said it best in the **Justice League Unlimited** episode *Epilogue* :

> I've known Bruce Wayne for over fifty years, and I've been keeping an eye on you your whole life. You're not Bruce's clone, you're his son. There are similarities, mind you, but more than a few differences too. You don't quite have his magnificent brain, for instance; you do have his heart though, and for all that fierce exterior I've never met anyone who cared as deeply about his fellow man as Bruce Wayne, except maybe you...

So no, Miller's version *Was not* canon before, and in many ways still isn't *totally* canon, but it *does* fall "in line" with current canon to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Russhiro's answer, while *The Dark Knight Returns* may have been the template for grim-and-gritty Batman, it was Miller's *Year One*, published a year later in 1987, that I think really set a template for Batman's character that was picked up by the DCAU. This version of Bruce Wayne, while just starting out, showed what we've come to expect from Batman: he's brutal when he has to be, quite willing to beat and terrorize authority figures to get results, has access to high-tech gadgets he uses to get out of some tight spots, plays the role of Bruce Wayne, Rich Lecherous Idiot With No Day Job to the hilt...and yet risks his life to save a cat and is willing to give up everything he's worked so carefully to create (his secret identity, even his life) in order to save a baby.