# In what issue did Batman survive the vacuum of space?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, space, episode-identification

In what issue did Batman survive the vacuum of space? I heard this a long time ago while watching Death Battle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[JLA: Welcome to the Working Week](http://www.panelsonpages.com/?p=58737)*

[image: Batman can't breathe in space]

Comment: Again, awesomeness strikes. Thanks man.